# How to run the PHP functions after sending json data to the client side?

Tags: php, json, email

I have a registration page in client side, which accepts image and user details and sends a POST request to server.

In server I am uploading the image and inserting the url and other details to the user table. Once done I want to send email to the user with a welcome message. But, the uploading image and sending email causes increase in waiting time on the client side. Here is my function:

```
public function register($name,$email,$password,$about){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= ? LIMIT 1";
    $value = array($email);
    $data = $this->_dalObj->sqlQuery($query,$value);
    if(isset($data['data'][0]['email']) == $email){
        return array("status" => 0, "message" => "Email Address Already Registered With Us!", "data" => "");
    }
    $password = base64_encode($password);
    $password = md5($password);
    $access_token = md5($email.$password.$email.time());
    $target = "uploads/";
    $user_image = $this->_funcObj->uploadImage($target, 'image');
    $user_image = $user_image['image'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (name,email,password,access_token,image,about) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $value = array($name,$email,$password,$access_token,$user_image,$about);
    $data = $this->_dalObj->sqlQuery($query,$value);
    $mail = $this->_funcObj->send_email($email,"Registration","You have Successfully Registered with us!");
    return array("status" => 1, "message" => "Registration Successful!", "data" => $mail);
}
```

What I would like to do is upload the image and insert the details to database then send response to client `Registration Successful`. Once the response is sent the email function should be called so the waiting time at front-end is reduced. There is a solution to use corn job but is there any other solutions to this type of problem.

P.S: I am using `PHPMailer` to send emails

Comment: Sounds to me like AJAX is the concept you are looking for. I would recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO if you do not want to use cron jobs, and you're using jQuery or something similar, you can use the return array as data to be read by js in order to ajax call another server script for sending that email.
Probably, at your place I'll do something like this:

- upload the image and set somewhere on a mysql table a flag "email_sent" to 0
- return json_encoded data to the caller js script
- Show something to the user, just for keep it busy reading for a while
- ajax call a script to send email to the user, if successful, flag email_sent to 1 and, possibly, warn him about the sent email.

Here's a very simple example

*** upload_image.php ***

```
<?php
/* here you stuff for the upload*/
echo json_encode(array('is_error' => false, 'userID' => 5, 'sendemail' => true));
```

*** send_email.php ***

```
<?php
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
/* do your mailer stuffs here */
try {
   $sql['sql'] = "UPDATE table SET email_sent = ?";
   $sql['params'] = array('i',1);
   $sql['stmt'] = $YOURCLASSTOMANAGESQLQUERIES->query($sql['sql'],$sql['params']);

   echo json_encode(array('is_error' => false, 'email_sent' => true));
} catch(Exception $ex)
{
   echo json_encode(array('is_error' => true, 'email_sent' => false, 'error_message' => $ex->getMessage()));
}
```

*** your js file ***

```
var OBJ = {
    upload : function(){
        var file_input = $('input[name="fileUpload"]'),
            file_data = file_input.prop('files')[0],
            form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('fileUpload', file_data);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'upload_image.php',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data : form_data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (d) {
            if (d.is_error === true) {
                // do something with you errors
            }

            // show something to the user, then call:
            OBJ.sendemail(d);
        }).fail(function (j) {
            // do something with your j.responseText
        });
    },

    sendemail : function(data){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'send_email.php',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data : data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (d) {
            if (d.is_error === true) {
                // do something with you errors
            }

            // do something
        }).fail(function (j) {
            // do something with your j.responseText
        });
    },

    init : function(){
        $(document)
        .off('upload','sendemail')
        .on('click.upload','button[data-upload="true"]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            OBJ.upload();
        });
    }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    OBJ.init();
});
```

Comment: Actually this is a great idea. I don't know why I didn't think of this. I was too focused on server side I guess Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

Well i will recommend you to use cron job as it is much easier and clean solution and user call should not be dependent on emial library ..